# Dispaly SharedPreference Items in ListView on Widget

Tags: android, listview, widget, sharedpreferences

I have a list of ingredients that I am storing in `SharedPreferences` and passing to my widget. Below is where I store them into SharedPreferences after clicking on the respective ingredient from a `RecyclerView`:

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String id = mRecipeDataSet.get(position).getId();
        final String recipeName = mRecipeDataSet.get(position).getName();
        final List<Ingredients> ingredients = mRecipeDataSet.get(position).getIngredients();
        holder.mTextView.setText(recipeName);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //STORING INGREDIENTS TO SHAREPREFERNCES
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                for (Ingredients ingredients : ingredients){
                    editor.putString(ingredients.getIngredient(), ingredients.getIngredient());
                    editor.putString(ingredients.getIngredient(), ingredients.getMeasure());
                    editor.putString(ingredients.getIngredient(), ingredients.getQuantity());
                }
                   editor.apply();


            }
        });

    }
```

Below is my **AppWidgetProvider** where I am attempting to retrieve the items from preferences and display via a `ListView`on my widget. I am struggling with the concept of a `RemoteViewService` as it seems overly complex compared to the standard way of setting a ListView adapter and displaying items accordingly:

```
public class BakingWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String RECIPE_NAME = "RECIPE_NAME";
    //TODO: Another method of getting information from Activity/Fragment/POJO to widget - unclear why I would need to do this but also added this string to my manifest
    public static final String ACTION_TEXT_CHANGED = "kitchenpal.troychuinard.com.kitchenpal.TEXT_CHANGED";
    private static final String PREFS = "PREFS";
    private static final String INGREDIENTS = "INGREDIENTS";
    private static String mRecipeName;
    private static String mRecipeIngredients;

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mRecipeName = preferences.getString(RECIPE_NAME,null);
        mRecipeIngredients = preferences.getString(INGREDIENTS, null);
        Log.v(INGREDIENTS, mRecipeIngredients);
        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.baking_widget_provider);
        //TODO: I can successfully display the ingredients, however I do not know how to organize into a ListView
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.selected_recipe, mRecipeIngredients);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.chef, pIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to apply the changes to `SharedPreferences` using `editor.apply();` in your `onBindViewHolder(...)` method.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the question posed, which is asking how to display existing data in an App Widget `ListView`.